# Java Split String using regular expression

Tags: java, string-parsing

I have `string` that reads `ParseGeoPoint[30.132531,31.312511]`. How can I get the coordinates saved in `double` variables. i.e. I want to have double `lat = 30.132531;` and `double lang = 31.312511;`

Here is what I have tried:

```
String myText = "ParseGeoPoint[30.132531,31.312511]";
String [] latlong= myText.split("["); //it needs an escape character
String [] latlong2= latlong[1].split(",");
Double lat = Double.parseDouble(latlong2[0]);
String[] latlong3= latlong2[1].split("]");//also an escape character is needed here
Double lang = Double.parseDouble(latlong3[0]);
```

Two things:
How to split on the square bracket given that it needs an escape character?
Second, I feel it is too much to do it in this way. There must be simpler way. What is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to split on the square bracket given that it needs an escape character?

I guess you mean that this doesn't compile:

> ```
> String [] latlong= myText.split("[");
> ```

To make it compile, escape the `[`:

```
String [] latlong= myText.split("\\[");
```

---

Here's another way to extract the doubles from the string using regular expressions:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("ParseGeoPoint\\[([\\d.-]+),([\\d.-]+)]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(myText);
if (matcher.matches()) {
    lat = Double.parseDouble(matcher.group(1));
    lang = Double.parseDouble(matcher.group(2));
}
```

---

Another way is using substrings:

```
int bracketStartIndex = myText.indexOf('[');
int commaIndex = myText.indexOf(',');
int bracketEndIndex = myText.indexOf(']');
lat = Double.parseDouble(myText.substring(bracketStartIndex + 1, commaIndex));
lang = Double.parseDouble(myText.substring(commaIndex + 1, bracketEndIndex));
```

Comment: would you explain the regular expression you used in the first answer?

Comment: The two `([\\d.-]+)` are the most important. These are called capture groups, the inside of the `(...)` can be extracted using `matcher.group(index)` calls. There I match 1 or more digits or dot or minus sign. It's not very strict, for example `---...` would match too, even though it's complete non-sense. But I hope you get the idea. The expression could be improved to make it more strict and robust. The rest of the expression outside the capture groups is fixed strings